# Яндекс почта вырезает style

Tags: php, email, вёрстка-email, яндекс-почта

Отправляю:

```
<tr><td valign="top"><span class="value" style="padding: 10px 0; margin:0; font-size: 17px; line-height: 24px; font-family: Segoe, Roboto, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #333;">Street / Street number</span></td></tr>
```

В Яндексе:

```
<tr><td valign="top"><span>Street / Street number</span></td></tr>
```

Куда девается атрибут **style**?

И почему появляется такое:

```
...
<td colspa="colspa" n="2" 
...
```

---

**Решение:** Я отправлял через PHP, а [там](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php) есть такая строка

> Каждая строка должна быть отделена символом CRLF (\r\n). Строки не должны быть длиннее 70 символов.

Соответственно и код:

```
// На случай если какая-то строка письма длиннее 70 символов мы используем wordwrap()
$message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");
```

Answer (score 2):

- Попробуйте заменить `span` на `font` или `p`.
- Ставьте вертикальные отступы с помощью дополнительных таблиц, но не с помощью паддингов.
- Прописывайте дополнительно стили шрифта, цвета на ячейку таблицы.

```html
<tr style="font-size: 17px; line-height: 24px; font-family: Segoe, Roboto, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #333333;">
  <td valign="top">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td height="10" style="height:10px;line-height:10px"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <p style="Margin:0; margin:0; padding:0;font-size: 17px; line-height: 24px; font-family: Segoe, Roboto, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #333333;">
      Street / Street number
    </p>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td height="10" style="height:10px;line-height:10px"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
```

---

Возможно `<td colspa="colspa" n="2"` появляется потому, что в вашей таблице есть ряды с двумя ячейками, а вы создаете новый ряд с одной ячейкой, в таком случае вам нужно прописать вашей ячейке `<td colspan="2"`.

Comment: Прошу прощения. Причина была в длине строки. Я через PHP отправлял, а он сам, видно, криво резал сообщение.

Comment: Хм, интересно. Спасибо за фидбэк.